# JLabel Background Image using palette in netbeans

Tags: java

I have added background image to my frame using Label from palette box. By using Icon in properties tool box, but the image is not getting fit to frame while maximizing in extended state. How to make background image that fits to screen using label properties tool box?

and my code for this is...

```
    bgLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel(); 
bgLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/mission/Bluebg1.jpg")));
 jPanel1.add(bgLabel); bgLabel.setBounds(-10, 0, 880, 470);
```

Comment: Show your code that what have you tried.

Comment: bgLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

bgLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/mission/Bluebg1.jpg"))); 

jPanel1.add(bgLabel);
bgLabel.setBounds(-10, 0, 880, 470);

Comment: this i got by right clicking the label in design and copied customize code. I did drag and drop. since i was creating frame using palette.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `Label` you have set using the Netbeans Drag and Drop facility has set its bounds... and on resizing the `Label` doesn't gets resized because it has its bounds fixed already...

As a result the icon on the label remains as it is...

If you want to make that `resizeable` then go to properties box and check both the check-boxes having

1. `Horizontal resizable.`
2. `Vertical resizable.`

That will do what you want.